# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I want to create an open source template in the future, of course first I'm doing practice with mevn stack without using the vue cli and manually configuring webpack, but at this moment I am getting this error.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/taskList.vue'
```

the link of github repository: [folders of components](https://github.com/michelnovellino/template-mevn/tree/master/src/app)

[repository link](https://github.com/michelnovellino/template-mevn)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo there, in your `main.js`, you need to change

```
import TaskList from './components/taskList.vue';
```

to

```
import TaskList from './components/tasksList.vue';
                                       ^
```

Comment: I really did not see the missing letter, I think it's time to leave the computer for now, thanks!